# Сдвигает изображение вправо

Tags: java, android, bitmap, камера, preview

Делаем снимок. Он приходит как байтовый массив, который мы собираем в битмап и сохраняем в файл. Но если разглядывать полученное изображение, можно заметить что оно чуть сдвинуто вправо. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Метод onPictureTaken в который приходит массив:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
    {
        imagesFolder.mkdir(); 
        MyappDir.mkdir();

        if (imagesFolder.listFiles().length == 0 | schet == null)
        {
                DataOutputStream out = null;
                Integer n = Integer.valueOf(1);
                try
                {
                    out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(schet));
                    out.writeInt(n.intValue());
                    out.close();
                    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_" + n + ".jpg");
                Bitmap imageBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramArrayOfByte.length);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                imageBmp = imageBmp.createBitmap(imageBmp, 0, 0, 4128, 2322, matrix, true);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image); 
                imageBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);
                fos.close();
                                    galleryAddPic();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я уверен, что оно перестанет *сдвигаться*, если вы уберете эту строчку

```
imageBmp = imageBmp.createBitmap(imageBmp, 0, 0, 4128, 2322, matrix, true);
```

Или, если переворачивать его необходимо, то замените ее на следующую:

```
imageBmp = imageBmp.createBitmap(imageBmp, 0, 0, imageBmp.getWidth(), imageBmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Так оно получается не на весь экран.

Comment: @Никитоs, видимо, разрешение экрана не пропорционально разрешению камеры. Выбирайте, или обрезать придется, или не на весь экран. Можете еще попробовать растянуть, например

Comment: Взял ширину и высоту дисплея смартфона, создал scaled bitmap, изображение растягивается по высоте на весь экран и выходит слишком вытянутым по высоте. Не подскажете что еще можно придумать?

Comment: @Никитоs  Я же говорю - обрезать можно.

Comment: А как обрезать?

Comment: @Никитоs, чтобы вам ответили на этот вопрос, задайте его, как новый. Иначе от него не будет никакой пользы этому форуму.